# connecting lines between two components in flex4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, lines

Hey,
i need to connect between a image(a) with a lines to another image(b).. these lines have to start from center of (A) to bottom or top of image (B) and it has to b in a vertical hierarchy 
thats i there could b multiple images connected to image a in hierarchy...

i have used a components for image and also for lines..so how can i find center point of component...

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Ive used this componnet before: 
http://sammyjoeosborne.com/Examples/Connector/ConnectorExample.html

The connectors automatically connect from center point to centre point of the objects, it may be of some help.

Comment: hey that one is gr8...how did u did dat...? can u  elaborate a little

Comment: Its not my code, I just used it. The source is available here: http://sammyjoeosborne.com/SourceCode/Connector/ConnectorSource.html

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question about the center point of a component, it would be x + w/2 and y + h/2.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks i did followed this...but i have problem of gap in between dem...so still on it...lines connect but nt with the images